# Removing ActiveAdmin generated comments routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I've disabled Comments through ActiveAdmin's configuration mechanism so that they no longer appear as a menu item, but the routes are still there and, as a result, we're getting a minor failure during a security scan.

I've tried "overriding" the routes with my own definition in routes.rb, but the newly defined routes just appear along side the original ActiveAdmin ones and the former seem to take precedence.

How can I remove or override these routes?

```
                  admin_comments GET      /admin/comments(.:format)                                                       admin/comments#index
                                 POST     /admin/comments(.:format)                                                       admin/comments#create
                   admin_comment GET      /admin/comments/:id(.:format)                                                   admin/comments#show
```

Comment: can you post what you have in the routes file?

Comment: @MZaragoza I don't have anything in the routes.rb file for comments at all, if that's what you mean. The ActiveAdmin routes are generated within that gem.

Comment: There is no way to remove the routes, the reason is that you can reenable the comments per resource.

Comment: @TimoSchilling Thanks. Do you know of any way to override them with my own routes.rb definitions?

Comment: You can remove the `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` form your routes file and add all routes by hand, Or you maybe find a way in rails to remove the routes from the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround that prevents the routes from being generated that works for my purposes. It's not ideal, but if you really want them gone, this works with ActiveAdmin 2.6.1 (latest version at the time I'm posting). I didn't have any success figuring out a way to remove routes from Rails and didn't want to skip `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)`/write them all out by hand.

```rb
# in config/intializers/active_admin.rb
# or anywhere else after ActiveAdmin is loaded but before ActiveAdmin.routes gets called

module NamespaceWithoutComments
  def register(resource_class, options = {}, &block)
    super unless resource_class == ActiveAdmin::Comment
  end
end

module ActiveAdmin
  class Namespace
    prepend NamespaceWithoutComments
  end
end
```

Consider before using, because it's a bit of a risky option:

- future compatibility concerns - if any of the active admin code that this references changes and you update, this snippet might cause problems in your app
- It's at odds with the maintainers' stated intention of allowing comments to be turned on for an individual resource
- it invalidates the config.comments setting - if you later want to have comments, this needs to go